# why right constraint got error and width constraint work well using masonry?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, masonry

I use masonry for layout my UI.

And in my viewController, I add a headView in a tableView, and in headView, added a button.

when I add right constraint to the button, it got warning/error below:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5fa9ead00 UIButton:0x7ff5fa9e4ae0.left == UIView:0x7ff5fa9dd780.left + 20>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5fa9eae80 UIButton:0x7ff5fa9e4ae0.right == UIView:0x7ff5fa9dd780.right - 20>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5fad3ac10 UIView:0x7ff5fa9dd780.width ==>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5fa9eae80 UIButton:0x7ff5fa9e4ae0.right == UIView:0x7ff5fa9dd780.right - 20>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

my code just like below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    UIView * headView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MainScreenWidth, 438)];
    headView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.headView = headView;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headView;


    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.headView addSubview:button];
    [button setTitle:@"a button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickThawButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.clipsToBounds = YES;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(@20);
        //make.right.equalTo(@-20);  // The error line
        make.width.equalTo(@(MainScreenWidth - 40)); //I slove the problem by this.
        make.top.equalTo(otherView.mas_bottom).offset(25);
        make.height.equalTo(@55);
    }];

}
```

Though I slove the problem  by constraint width, I want know why this happens. Or are there any tips?

Comment: Do you get error when you set left, right and width constraints all together? or you got error when you set left and right constraints?

Comment: not set together.  I set left right and it got error. I set left,width and it works well.

Comment: According to the log message, `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5fad3ac10 UIView:0x7ff5fa9dd780.width ==>` is conflict with the `right space with button`, because the button size cannot be negative(below zero). Somehow the superview's width of the `button` set to under 20 and it makes the button's width negative. Try to set the tableView's frameWidth over 20.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint should looks like this:

```
[button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.headView).with.offset(20);
        make.right.equalTo(self.headView).with.offset(-20);
        make.top.equalTo(otherView.mas_bottom).offset(25);
        make.height.equalTo(@55);
 }];
```

You want to snap button's right edge of to its superview with `-20` offset, not to the point with `x` coordinate equal `-20`